# Display rows in 2 columns

Tags: row

I would like to display my row on 2 columns,

but for a reason it is only displaying the first entry on 2 rows.('name' on 1 row /'grouped_id' other row.
Not all entries of my database.

I missed something know with $row=.

Can you help me ? I would like display 'name' 
 'grouped_id' on each row:

my code

```
<title>TITLE</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {background-color: #000000;}
table {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;

}
table, .table {
    color: #fff;
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight:800;
font-weight:Extra-bold;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #60451e;
}
</style>
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        include_once("inc/db_connect.php");
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT  name, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ' | ') as grouped_id  FROM developers GROUP BY name";
        $resultSet = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
        ?>
        <table id="editableTable" class="table table-bordered">

            <tbody>
<?php
 
// represents your database rows
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet);
 
$length = count($rows);
$halfIndex = ceil($length / 2);
 
$currentRow = 0;
while ($currentRow < $halfIndex) {
    $leftIndex = $currentRow;
    $rightIndex = $halfIndex + $currentRow;
 
    $leftColumn = $rows[$leftIndex] ?? '--';
    $rightColumn = $rows[$rightIndex] ?? '--';
 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$leftColumn}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$rightColumn}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 
    $currentRow++;
}
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$leftColumn` and `$rightColumn` are not pointing on the same row index. Check whether `$leftIndex` and `$rightIndex` are set to the correct values.

Comment: This the calculation to display 2 columns.. And should be the result of entries of $row splitter in 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
or here for a brief summary https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

The result of `mysqli_fetch_array` is a an array of array: a list of samples where each sample is a list of fields from the query table.

Comment: To be honest, I am not completely sure that tech_array is the right thing to set for $row=, This is the point, I would like to display all entries of my database. Fetch_array looked the most obvious to me